# phpinfo() doesn't show phar enabled/disabled

Tags: php, phar

I am using PHP Version 5.3.15 on OpenSUSE. Following is in my php.ini:

```
[Phar]  
; http://php.net/phar.readonly  
phar.readonly = Off

; http://php.net/phar.require-hash  
phar.require_hash = Off

;phar.cache_list =
```

When I try to execute phar using CLI, I get a class not found error for Phar:

```
php composer.phar install  
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phar' not found in /srv/www/htdocs/composer.phar on line 13
```

I tried searching everywhere but can't seem to find a reason. Please help.

Comment: Do you actually have the [`php5-phar`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php5-phar) package installed?

Comment: settings those settings will not enable Phar. You need to enable in php.ini the extension or compile it into PHP.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: Thanks a lot. That was the problem. it solved the issue. Please put this as an answer and I will accept that. I read everywhere that for PHP 5.3.x there is no need to install phar as it was part of the PHP install, which was not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the [`php5-phar`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php5-phar) RPM package installed.  After installing it with your favorite package manager (e.g. YaST), it should work.